# Calculating rolling percentage change by category in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

[image: data table]

I have a SQL data table like this, and I wanted to calculate the rolling percentage change (by row and category). So that the result looks like this below

[image: result table]

The SQL query I use is really slow and it takes forever to calculate it when there are thousands of categories, do you have an idea what's going on? Or any improvement?

First create a sample data_table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_table (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    num INT,
    category VARCHAR(10),
    price FLOAT(20,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO data_table(num,category,price)
VALUES(1,"A","10"),
      (2,"A","20"),
      (3,"A","30"),
      (1,"B","20"),
      (2,"B","30"),
      (3,"B","40");
```

SQL for calculating percentage change:

```
SELECT 
     A.*, 
     CASE WHEN (A.price IS NULL OR B.price IS NULL OR B.price=0) THEN 0 ELSE
        (A.price - B.price)/(B.price) *100 END AS perc
FROM (SELECT
    num,
    category,
    price
  FROM data_table
  ) A LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    num,
    category,
    price
  FROM data_table
  ) B
ON (A.num = B.num+1) AND A.category=B.category;
```

Comment: Please add the CREATE TABLE statement and replace the images of data with markdown tables and / or INSERT statements.

Comment: I just added the SQL for the data creation @nnichols

Comment: Adding an index on (category, num) will probably help.

Comment: After you upgrade to MySQL, a different solution, using `LAG()` will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use user variables -

```sql
SELECT
    dt.*,
    IF(@prev_cat <> category, NULL, ROUND((price - @prev_price) / @prev_price * 100, 1)) AS perc,
    @prev_cat := category,
    @prev_price := price
FROM data_table dt, (SELECT @prev_cat := 0, @prev_price := 0) vars
ORDER BY category, num;
```

If you want to update your table with this perc value you can use -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `data_table` 
  ADD COLUMN `perc` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL AFTER `price`;

UPDATE `test`.`data_table` dt
JOIN (
    SELECT
        dt.*,
        IF(@prev_cat <> category, NULL, ROUND((price - @prev_price) / @prev_price * 100, 1)) AS perc_calc,
        @prev_cat := category,
        @prev_price := price
    FROM data_table dt, (SELECT @prev_cat := 0, @prev_price := 0) vars
    ORDER BY category, num
) z ON dt.id = z.id
SET dt.perc = z.perc_calc;
```

If you were on MySQL 8 this would be a bit easier with LAG() -

```sql
SELECT dt.*,
    ROUND((price - LAG(price, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC)) / LAG(price, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC) * 100, 1) AS `prev1`,
    ROUND((price - LAG(price, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC)) / LAG(price, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC) * 100, 1) AS `prev2`,
    ROUND((price - LAG(price, 20) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC)) / LAG(price, 20) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num ASC) * 100, 1) AS `prev20`
FROM data_table dt;
```

Comment: This works like a charm, it is so fast now. However, there's one thing, if the `price` of first row of every category is `0`, the `perc` for that first row should be `null` instead of 0. Do you have an idea how to do that? Currently it is `0` in this kind of scenario,

Comment: Have changed 0 to NULL in the IF statement

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome! Out of interest did you try the additional key on (category, num)?

Comment: No, because I created this `num` column using another SQL statements, and I already have a primary key in my original data which I did not include in this code. I can try it if you think it is an good idea.

Comment: Just curious to see how much the composite index improves the performance of your original query. It's amazing how much you can learn by being curious.

Comment: That's very true. I will give it a try later and let you know. I have a follow up question if you don't mind. How do I update the `data_table` using statement you wrote above? Because I was trying to create a new data table from this statement using `CREATE TABLE perc_temp`, however, it is taking a really long time because my data is too big. The whole `SELECT` statement takes 15-20 sec to execute, but by adding the `CREATE TABLE` it takes minutes to run. How do I update the `perc` column to the existing `data_table` ?

Comment: What sort of size is it? Do you mean you want to add the perc column to existing table and then update its value?

Comment: The `data_table` has 5 million rows. Yes, "add the perc column to existing table and then update its value" would be great!

Comment: I have added the update statement to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will update you with the outcome as well as "adding index on (category, num)" later today. Really appreciate your help and advice!

Comment: I create an index and left joined which works fine now. One last question... Currently this is calculating percentage change from previous row. Is that possible to calculate from 2nd or 3rd previous row? so it's kind of like `ROUND((price - @second_prev_price) / @second_prev_price * 100, 1))` @nnichols

Comment: I got it work, so for 2day is `@prev2_price := @prev_price, @prev_price := price`, 3day is `@prev3_price := @prev2_price, @prev2_price := @prev_price, @prev_price := price`. The question is if I want to do 20day, I have to add 20 user-defined variable which adds 20 column and it's really big. Do you have a better idea? P.S. but I think the performance will not that bad because I only need to calculate the 20th percentage change, not from 1-20.

Comment: Well done! As Rick James mentioned above, moving to MySQL 8 would be a good move, then you could do this [using lag()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag), a window function. I will add an example in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I would much love to move on to 8.0 however, there are some tech constrain preventing upgrading for now. But I will keep that in mind. Thank you for your help!